# Como fazer botão piscar no Android.

Tags: android, xml

Olá, gostaria de fazer um botão(`Button`) piscar no Android.

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "piscar"? Pode ser cor do background, cor do texto ou até mesmo mostrar e exibir o button. Adicione mais alguns detalhes à pergunta.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use uma *Animation* para obter esse efeito

```
private Animation animation;
private Button btn;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0); // Altera alpha de visível a invisível
    animation.setDuration(500); // duração - meio segundo
    animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE); // Repetir infinitamente
    animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE); //Inverte a animação no final para que o botão vá desaparecendo
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_btn);
    btn.startAnimation(animation);

}
```

Se quiser que a animação seja parada após o botão ser clicado:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View view) {
        view.clearAnimation(); //Pára a animação
    }
});
```

Para iniciar novamente a animação faça: `btn.startAnimation(animation);`

Adaptado desta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4852468/2556111)